Clarification on the Meaning of LastModificationTime in CyberArk Account Objects
I'm working with CyberArk's REST API, and I'm trying to understand the exact meaning of the LastModificationTime property on an Account object. The documentation states that this property represents "the date the account was last modified.".
What I’m unclear about is whether this timestamp reflects:

Any modification to the account (e.g., changes to account attributes like the account name, description, or tags).
Only changes to the account's password.

For example, if I update the account's name or description without changing the password, will the LastModificationTime be updated?
I'm confused because the property is nested on the account object as .secretManagement.lastModificationTime, which implies this date is related more to the secret than to the state of the account.
I need this clarification because I’m trying to use this property to monitor password updates specifically, and I want to make sure I’m interpreting it correctly.
Any insight from someone familiar with CyberArk or its API behavior would be greatly appreciated.

It turns out, at least in CyberArk v12.6, lastModificationTime from account details API will not always match the value displayed in either PVWA or EVD.
Changes that affect properties on the account don’t seem to affect the lastModificationTime API account property. However, actions like triggering Reconcile on the account will update the lastModificationTime to the current date… and shockingly this happens even if the account can’t reconcile. This behavior is just one of the many bugs found in and around CyberArk.
The value presented in the EVD CAFiles.CAFLastModifiedDate  seems to show a better more accurate value. But there you’re stuck with the slow refresh period.
